# How to toggle certain flot chart series?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

Being given this example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-toggle/index.html. Is there a way to don't make it work dynamically? I don't want to have a checkbox for each cauntry, but only for two of them (for example: a checkbox for USA and another for Russia). Hope I made myself understood. How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from that example that sets up the check boxes:

```
    // insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
            "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
            "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
            + val.label + "</label>");
    });
```

Declare an array of the keys of the countries you want:

```
var countriesToShow = ["usa", "russia"];
```

Now change that `each()` call to check each data item key for inclusion in that array and only output the checkbox+label if it's there.

```
$.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
    if (countriesToShow.includes(key)) {
        choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
            "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
            "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
            + val.label + "</label>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Danke for your reply! Doesn't display anymore the checkboxes.
You suggested the code to be like: 

var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
var countriesToShow = ["usa", "russia"];
$.each(datasets, function (key, val) {
if (countriesToShow.includes(key)) {
                    choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
                        "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
                        "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
                        + val.label + "</label>");
                }
            });
No?